# How to work with a set having many time series data each having average length 20?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series, bigdata, forecasting

I have large set of short time series data (average length of short time series = 20). The total size of the data is around 6 GB.
Current system working in following way:
1) Load 6 GB data into RAM.
2) Process the data.
3) Put the forecast value corresponding to each time series in excel.

The problem is every time i run the above system it is taking nearly 1 hour in my 8 GB RAM PC.
Please suggest a better way to reduce my time.

Answer (score 0):

- Use a faster programming language. For example, you can prefer using Julia or C++ instead of MATLAB or Python.
- Try to make your code more efficient. For example, instead of passing data to your functions by copying them (pass by value), try to pass them as reference ([What's the difference between passing by reference vs. passing by value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value)). Use more efficient data structures.
- Divide your dataset into smaller parts. Work on each small part separately. Then, merge the outputs at the end.